# accessing json content from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a dictionary containing Json data. I am not able to handle the data inside it. I tried enumerating but keeps failing.

```
This is the data format I am getting back using NSLog:

2013-03-21 12:48:36.973 SaleItems[21009:c07] {
    article = "Surface's other shoe is about to drop: the full Windows 8, Intel Core-driven Surface is headed to stores in just a few weeks.";
    id = 2;
    title = "Microsoft Surface Pro hits U.S. and Canada ";
}
2013-03-21 12:48:36.974 SaleItems[21009:c07] {
    article = "Hit by growing demand for Samsung devices, the iPhone will lose smartphone market share for the current quarter, says a Citi analyst";
    id = 3;
    title = "iPhone to shed market share";
}
2013-03-21 12:48:36.974 SaleItems[21009:c07] {
    article = "The carrier says it plans to buy wireless spectrum and network assets from Atlantic Tele-Network, aka Alltel, in an effort to boost its spectrum coffers.";
    id = 4;
    title = "AT&T spends $780 million ";
}
```

I know from the looks of it that I am getting back a dictionary of arrays. How can I access the arrays and elements inside them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have key as article, id and title, simply access the object in loop as:

**I am assuming that you have a Class called SalesItem and the above log are from each object of that*

```
for(SalesItem *object in SalesItem){
    NSLog(@"Article : %@",object[@"article"]);
    NSLog(@"Id : %@",object[@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"Title : %@",object[@"title"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked indeed